# memory order of structs and ints

Tags: c, memory, struct, unions

I want to make a union with a struct and and a uint64_t, so I can reference individual uint16_ts with the struct, and have them be concatenated in the uint64_t. I made this test program:

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "stdint.h"
struct test_struct{
    uint16_t stuff;
    uint16_t a;
    uint16_t b;
    uint16_t c;
};

union test_union{
    struct test_struct str;
    uint64_t uint;
};    

int main(){
    struct test_struct x = {
        .stuff = 0x0000,
        .a = 0x1234,
        .b = 0x5678,
        .c = 0x9ABC
    };
    union test_union y;
    y.str = x;

    printf("y.uint: %llX\n", y.uint);
}
```

The output becomes:

```
y.uint: 9ABC567812340000
```

which is counter-intuitive to me (it shoud be 0000123456789ABC, or 123456789ABC). Can someone explain to me why the elements in the struct seem to be reversed?

EDIT:
For future reference: The endianness answers had me confused, because, the uint16_ts were printed in the right order. But this is, of course, because they themselves are stored little-endian.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are on a little-endian platform, and the bytes stored first (with the lowest addresses) end up in the least significant bits (right-hand side when printed) of the combined `uint64_t`.

If you run the same code on a big-endian platform, you would get the result you expect. Your code as it stands is not portable across systems with different endianness.

Answer (score 0):

It's all to do with [Endianess](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness). I don't think the C/C++ language define the way this works, leaving it up to the implementation / target CPU to define. On a big-endian CPU you'd have got what you were expecting.

Answer (score 0):

If your processor is "little-endian", the LSB stored on the lowest address, so that's a normal output. On Intel's x86 platform, normally it's little-endian. By contrast, Motorola's PowerPC is big-endian, which is to say, the MSB stored on the lowest address.

Answer (score 0):

This is because of [Little Endianess](http://www.cs.umd.edu/class/sum2003/cmsc311/Notes/Data/endian.html).